# Deleting and shifting objects in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I've been working on a project that creates an array of objects(hardware tools) from a class I made, called `ToolItem`. It looks at such:

`private ToolItem[] toolArray = new ToolItem[10];`

```
for (int i = 0; i < toolArray.length; i++)
        {
            toolArray[i] = new ToolItem();
            System.out.println(toolArray[i]);
        }
```

The current class I am working on, called `ToolWarehouse`, is designed to manipulate the data using methods like insert, search, delete ect. When creating the delete method, we are instructed to search for a unique ID and if it matches, set all data members to 0. After, we are instructed to delete the member of the array and shift everything to the left. The instructions on how to shift the array was never taught/mentioned, so I did some digging and came up with this:

```
public void delete(int ID)
    {
        testArray = searchArray(ID);   //method used to search array for specified ID

        for (index = 0; index < toolArray.length; index++)
        {
            if (testArray == index)    
            {
                toolArray[index].setQuality(0);
                toolArray[index].setToolName("");
                toolArray[index].setID(0);
                toolArray[index].setNumberInStock(0);
                toolArray[index].setPrice(0.0);

                System.arraycopy(toolArray, 1, toolArray, 0, toolArray.length - 1);

                numberOfItems--;
            }
        }
    }//end delete
```

Here is searchArray:

```
public int searchArray(int id)
    {
        for (index = 0; index < toolArray.length; index++)
        {
            if (toolArray[index].getToolID() == id)
            {
                System.out.println("ID found at location " + index);
                return index;
            }
        }   
        return -1;
    }//end searchArray
```

Where index is the spot in the array currently being evaluated. Now, is:

`System.arraycopy(toolArray, 1, toolArray, 0, toolArray.length - 1);` suitable for my purposes? I've been reading quite a bit on different ways to move items in an array and this seems to be the easiest way to do it, but most everyone used it with an arrayList which I can't use right now. Any feedback is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please indicate the types of `index`, `testArray`, and `toolArray` at least. We can deduce the types but your question does not contain a verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `arrayCopy` is not suitable. Note that you are copying `toolArray.length - 1` elements and I am not sure how you don't encounter `IndexOutOfBoundException`s.

Assuming `testArray`, and `index` are `int`s, and `toolArray` is an array of some object type, I think you can do this:

```
public void delete(int ID)
{
    testArray = searchArray(ID);   //method used to search array for specified ID

    // do things on the element that is returned from searchArray().
    toolArray[testArray].setQuality(0);
    toolArray[testArray].setToolName("");
    toolArray[testArray].setID(0);
    toolArray[testArray].setNumberInStock(0);
    toolArray[testArray].setPrice(0.0);

    // shift the rest.
    for (index = testArray + 1; index < toolArray.length; index++)
    {
        toolArray[index - 1] = toolArray[index];
    }

    // now toolArray[toolArray.length - 2] and toolArray[toolArray.length - 1]
    //points to the same object. Let's empty the last cell of the array
    toolArray[toolArray.length - 1] = null;
}//end delete
```

Note that every time you shift, there is a `null` cell(s) at the end of the array. I think you should consider using a collection that can grow or shrink, [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for example.

Comment: I just finished adding more info for you in an edit, but you beat me to it :) Thanks for the help though, maybe I was overthinking the whole situation. I'll test it and see how it goes.